# wavetable synth for iOS

Tags: ios, audio, playback, openal, waveform

I need to implement a wavetable player in my app. For different notes (polyphony) a note on and note off feature is needed (including looping for relevant sounds). 
The samples are available or can be converted by myself, the need is for a class that is capable of playing, looping and stopping the samples or waves. 
I found some open source project like fluid synth but here the question is for some sample code available for iOS or openAL.
Thank you in advance for any hints or snippets, 
regards, Koen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a look at the new Sampler audio unit in iOS5. This lets you play samples with pitch control at low latency.

There is some [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LoadPresetDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011214) from Apple.

Comment: However, do you have a snippet on how to load a SF2 sample? I would like to get SF2's into my app since this is possible. Unfortunately I do not see the right API to get this loaded.

Comment: I just found the following Tech note, maybe also helpful for other interested readers: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2283/_index.html

Comment: This answer just prevented me from wasting weeks doing it some other way. Apple's docs make it _really_ hard to discover this stuff.